# how to find the number of a specific data in SQL(MySQL)

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a data set called table which has 7 data such as [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]. I want to write a query to find out the number of a specific data. For example,I want to find 'd'.The sql should give me a number '3'. If I want to find 'g'.The sql should give me a number '6'.
Please help.Thank you.

Comment: So the array is stored in db?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? SQL Server, MySQL, or what?

Comment: This is a very poor question. To improve it: post a real table with create table. Also specify a database brand or just say 'agnostic sql'. Take in mind than the answer is different for each database branch. Also explain what did you tried.

Comment: May be this will help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738785/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738785/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-record)

Comment: thank you siva.That's is useful and help me a lot.

Comment: @siva, yes, this is nice explained. Michael, you can learn how to make question here: [How to find row number of a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738785/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-record)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Mysql which doesn't support ranking functions, then you can do this:

```
SELECT col, rank -1 as rownumber
FROM
(
  SELECT col, 
         @rownum := (@rownum + 1) AS rank
    FROM Table1 t, 
         (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) AS t
```

[mysql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e77572/3)

This will give you:

```
| col | RowNumber |
|-----|-----------|
|   a |         0 |
|   b |         1 |
|   c |         2 |
|   d |         3 |
|   e |         4 |
|   f |         5 |
|   g |         6 |
```

Then you can just filter on the the value you want.

Comment: Thank you Damien.

Comment: @Michael - You're welcome, please accept the answer if you found it helpful, thanks.