# Count the number of rows above a given row when a particular is order is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm trying to determine what 'page' a particular row of a table is on. Each page is 300 rows long and ordered by a HammingWt and Id. To determine this, I need to count all rows above and including a particular row. A simplifed table might look like this:

```
Id  HammingWt  FileName
------------------------
1     0         F1.png
3     0         F7.png
2     1         F8.png
4     1         F2.png
12    2         F5.png
14    2         F3.png
15    2         F6.png
8     3         F4.png
```

Something like:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM table [ABOVE] WHERE FileName = 'F3.png' ORDER BY HammingWt, ID;
```

And have it return 6 (the count of rows up to and including the F3.png row with Id = 14  when orderd by HammingWt and Id). I could then divide the returned count by the page length to determine which page the 'F3.png' row is on.

My actual table has approximately 1.5 * 10^6 rows. Id and FileName are unique, HammingWt is not.

Obviously, my select statement is not legal MS T-SQL since [ABOVE] is not a SQL keyword. Can someone show me a select statement that returns the count (as determined by the ORDER BY)?

I'm using MS SqlExpress (SQL Server 15.0.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `row_number()` and order it by `HammingWt` and `Id`.

```
select *
from   (
       select *
              ,row_number() over(order by HammingWt, Id) as rn
       from   t
       ) t
where  FileName = 'F3.png'
```

| Id | HammingWt | FileName | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 2 | F3.png | 6 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7zyzUDVT?hide=2)

Comment: I think it's close, but your fiddle returns 1, not 6.

Comment: @dei I'm not sure what you mean. My fiddle returns the result I posted. Do you need it to do something different?

Comment: I wanted the row number of a particular row (in my question, the row with Id = 14 and FileName = 'F3.png') which is 6. Your answer pointed me in the right direction (to use row_number()), though. Additional help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738785/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-record 
gave me the answer I was looking for:

WITH OrderedTable as (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY HammingWt, Id) as 'RowNumber' from t)
SELECT RowNumber FROM OrderedTable WHERE FileName = 'F3.png';

Comment: Change your select statement to

Comment: Change your select staement to:

WITH OrderedTable as (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY HammingWt, Id) as 'RowNumber' from t)
SELECT RowNumber FROM OrderedTable WHERE FileName = 'F3.png';

Comment: and I'll mark it as the answer (sorry, I'm having trouble adding markup to my comments)

Comment: @dei See updated answer

Comment: Your query was better than the one I came up with. Thanks!